# How to remove string between two strings?

Tags: text-processing

INPUT:

```
$ cat a.txt
FOO<td align="right" style='mso-number-format:"\[$-409\]m\/d\/yy\\ h\:mm\\ AM\/PM\;\@";' x:str>BAR
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ sed 's/SOMEMAGIC//g' a.txt
FOOBAR
```

**My question:** How can I remove that horrible "< td align......" part? This drives me nuts!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use this,

```
sed 's/^\([^<]*\)<.*>\(.*\)$/\1\2/g' file
```

**Explanation:**

`^\([^<]*\)<` -  Fetches any charcter not of `<` zero or more times from the starting position upto `<` and finally stores the fetched characters into a group.

`.*>`     - Matches any character zero or more times until it finds `>`.

`\(.*\)$` - Once the sed finds `>` character, it starts to store all the characters which are next to `>` upto the last into another group(*stores characters inbetween `>` and `$`*).

Finally `sed` prints only the stored groups(`\1`,`\2`) through back-reference.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
FOO<td align="right" style='mso-number-format:"\[$-409\]m\/d\/yy\\ h\:mm\\ AM\/PM\;\@";' x:str>BAR
$ sed 's/^\([^<]*\)<.*>\(.*\)$/\1\2/g' file.txt
FOOBAR
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that certainly is easy:

```
sed -i 's/<.*>//' file
```

There isn't too much to explain here:

- the `<` is the start of the part we want to match
- `.*` means any character (`.`) and any amount (`*`). This is a cannon to kill a mosquito, but should work for the non-esoteric examples
- `>` end of the match.

Here is live:

```
➜  ~  cat test 
FOO<td align="right" style='mso-number-format:"\[$-409\]m\/d\/yy\\ h\:mm\\ AM\/PM\;\@";' x:str>BAR
➜  ~  sed 's/<.*>//' test
FOOBAR
```

Answer (score 0):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -F'<.*>' -anle 'print @F' file
FOOBAR
```

Here we use regex `<.*>` as delimiter to split the line instead of removing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 sed -i 's/\(A\) B \(C\)/\1\2' /path/to/example.file
```

This will let string A and C stand and will cut out string B.
Replace the letters with your string/regex of choice.

Example

```
$ echo A B C | sed 's/\(A\) B \(C\)/\1\2'
$ AC
```

Comment: Or you could do ``echo AC`` or `printf '%s\n' FOOBAR` or `printf '%s%s\n' FOO BAR`.  But it’s implicit in questions like this that the OP wants a command / solution that doesn’t require that you know the specific strings in advance — like in [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131443/80216).  The only useful part of your answer is the `s/…/\1\2` part, which is already presented in that answer — and yours is ***worse*** than that (it won’t work), because you left off the final `/`.